# How to fix "Missing product attribute on result"

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to map over a graphql query with an imported component. The data is hooked up properly, but not passing. I get the error `Missing product attribute on result`

I narrowed down that the issue is in passing of the data.

Here is what I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="CoffeeSection">
    <h2>Coffees</h2>
    <div class="Cards">
      <CoffeeCard
        v-for="product of products"
        :key="product.id"
        :title="product.title"
        :slug="product.slug"
        :image="product.image.handle"
      ></CoffeeCard>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Am I appropriately mapping over the query here?

```
<script>
import CoffeeCard from "./CoffeeCard";

import gql from "graphql-tag";

const products = gql`
  query {
    products {
      title
      image {
        url
        handle
      }
      description
      price
      slug
      category {
        name
        description
        products {
          title
          image {
            url
            handle
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  name: "Coffees",
  data: () => ({
    loading: 0,
    products: []
  }),
  apollo: {
    $loadingKey: "loading",
    product: {
      query: products
    }
  },
  components: {
    CoffeeCard
  }
};
</script>
```

I get the error `Missing product attribute on result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smart query in `vue-apollo` is added by adding a property under `apollo` whose name doesn't start with a `$`. The name of this property should match both the value you initialize inside `data` to store the result as well as the name of the root field you're querying (i.e. `products`). However, it looks like instead of `products`, you've named the smart query `product` instead, causing the error you're seeing.

You can check out the [docs](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#name-matching) for additional details and examples.

Comment: Hey Daniel! Thanks for the response. I'd tried this before, but ran into another error inside of the child component. Now with your answer, had the confidence that this was the right way and found that error. Thank you!